# Wrong percentage with PHP

Tags: php

```
        $rewards = Reward::where('m_id', $module->id)->count();

        $percentage = 0;

        if($rewards != 0)
        {
            $count1 = $rewards / 100;
            $count2 = $count1 * $users;
            $count3 = 100 - $count2;
            echo $count3;
        }

        $rest = 100 - $percentage;

        $new = array(
            'name' => $module->name,
            'percentage' => $percentage,
            'rest' => $rest
        );
```

Hey,

this code above is a simple function to get percentage and then return a view with it.

The problem im having is that the $users are 569 right now and the reward is 1 so the correct percentage would be 0.569% out of 100%. But my code is return 5.69% out of 100%.

I have been searching around and i really can't find any way for noticing if this number should be with a zero or not! right now it should be 0.569% but i can't really just add a zero to it in the start as you can see.

Any solutions how to noticing if the number is only decimals or not ?

Comment: What do the variables mean?The equation is correct, `$count1 = 0.01` (from `$rewards/100`), `0.01 * 569 = 5.69`.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you try to do here, but 1% of 569 is 5.69. Why do you think it should be 0.569?

Comment: What represent each of `$count1`, `$count2` and `$count3`? Which of them are counts and which are percentages? You don't use them anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If reward is equal to one than according to your  calculation  count1=0.01 and  count2= 5.69 .percentage calculates correctly .